# Finding the mass of a cone using triple integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have a density $\rho(x,y,z) = 3-z$ and have converted my given information to form a triple integral equation for finding the volume of my cone in cylindrical coordinates and have found the volume and checked it to be correct so I know I currently have the correct equation to multiply the density into. I know I have to multiple my density by the volume to find the mass but I have no idea how to convert my density of $3-z$ into the cylindrical form $\rho(r,\theta,z)$.

Edit: Density was actually $\rho(x,y,z) = 3-z$, not $z-3$.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a density of $z-3$"? The density of the cone varies and is given by $\rho(x,y,z) = z-3$? How is the cone related to these coordinates? It is oriented along the $z$ axis? If so, converting $\rho$ to cylindrical coordinates $\rho(r,\theta, z)$ is trivial...

Comment: I'm not completely certain how to convert it though. It becomes something like (z+rcosθ+rsinθ) But I don't know how to get to that from z-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion between cylindrical and Cartesian coordinates is $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, $z = z$.

Thus, the density $\rho(x,y,z) = 3-z$ (Cartesian) becomes $\rho(r,\theta,z) = 3-z$ (cylindrical).

Comment: I did try using 3 - z before asking this question but produced a negative value for the density. Is negative density a thing?

Comment: No it is not. What are the bounds of your cone? If your cone does not go above the plane $z = 3$, then the density $3-z$ will be non-negative.

Comment: Bounds are z = 3 and sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
So θ is from 0 to 2pi, r is from 0 to the radius (3) and z is from 0 to 3 - r.

Comment: The cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $z = r$ when you convert to cylindrical. So the bounds for $z$ should be $r \le z \le 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, just like
$$\iiint_\Omega dV = \text{Volume}(\Omega),$$
so too
$$\iiint_\Omega \rho(x,y,z) dxdydz = \text{Mass}(Omega),$$
where $\rho$ denotes density and $\Omega$ denotes your region.

Comment: It's as user7530 commented, I have density p(x,y,z) = z - 3 and wish to convert p to (r,θ,z) but I'm confused as to how :s